# Scale animation on gridview (gridview childs are moving to bottom while using bringToTop())

Tags: android

I am trying to apply scale animation on GridView. My purpose is that when I click on any grid-child , it should be animated up to (scale-X from 1f to 2f & scale-Y from 1 to 2). So when I applied the animation on grid, and when I clicked on any child then this child become zoomed in which was as expected but it was zoomed in beneath the greater indexed children. so that was also expected behaviour because grid is maintaining stack. then I used bringToTop() on the child. using this, clicked children started moving to the bottom and hen animate.

then to overcome this problem I applied following properties on the grid ,

1: clipChildren(false),

2: animateLayoutChanges(true)

Now gridview behaviour is very strange which i can not understand. Story is , when I click some index (lets say 6), then sixth indexed child goes to the bottom and animate on that position(bottom). and when I click on the sixth index again then child scales up perfectly while staying on 6th index(same index).

My question is that why is GridView behaving like this ? what is the fix to this problem.

Is there any logical error that I am doing or this is gridview's default behaviour?

is there anybody who faced this scene and overcome this problem ? I have searched a lot , could not troubleshoot this problem . any help would be appreciated.